# Adjective for describing a shirt being worn in the wrong way

Tags: word-request

What adjective would you use to describe the way this shirt is being worn?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shirt is worn *backwards*:

> with the back foremost

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backwards))

The definition also implies the front is at the back, of course. Apparently, [it is/was a fashion trend](https://metro.co.uk/2016/04/05/fashion-bloggers-have-started-wearing-their-shirts-backwards-and-no-one-knows-what-to-think-5796108/), but it can be used for 'accidents' as well.

Comment: You could also call it "back to front." (Chiefly British English) https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/back-to-front